# How to get prerequisites with respect to the target in Makefile (GNU Make)?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Is there a way to get the prerequisite corresponding to a target in the Makefile (GNU Make)?

For instance, consider the following Makefile:

```
CXX = g++
CFLAGS = -Wall
MODULE_NAME = myRenderer
BUILD_DIR = bin

SOURCE_FILES = renderer/tracer.cpp renderer/lights/DiffuseLight.cpp renderer/materials/ScatterUtils.cpp
OBJECT_FILES = $(patsubst %,$(BUILD_DIR)/%, $(notdir $(SOURCE_FILES:.cpp=.o)))

$(BUILD_DIR)/$(MODULE_NAME): $(OBJECT_FILES)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^

$(OBJECT_FILES): $(SOURCE_FILES)
    @mkdir -p "$(BUILD_DIR)"
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -I. -c $< -o $@
```

when I run make, I can see that the following commands get executed:

```
g++ -Wall -I. -c renderer/tracer.cpp -o bin/tracer.o
g++ -Wall -I. -c renderer/tracer.cpp -o bin/DiffuseLight.o
g++ -Wall -I. -c renderer/tracer.cpp -o bin/ScatterUtils.o
g++ -o bin/myRenderer bin/tracer.o bin/DiffuseLight.o bin/ScatterUtils.o
```

And obviously, this fails to build the executable as it's using only the first prerequisite i.e. `renderer/tracer.cpp` to generate all the object files because I am using the `$<` automatic variable in the recipe command for the `$(OBJECT_FILES)` target.

I wish to know how to fix my Makefile to be able to execute these commands:

```
g++ -Wall -I. -c renderer/tracer.cpp -o bin/tracer.o
g++ -Wall -I. -c renderer/lights/DiffuseLight.cpp -o bin/DiffuseLight.o
g++ -Wall -I. -c renderer/materials/ScatterUtils.cpp -o bin/ScatterUtils.o
g++ -o bin/myRenderer bin/tracer.o bin/DiffuseLight.o bin/ScatterUtils.o
```

I cannot seem to find the right automatic variable or a way to fetch the right source file to build a given object file.

Comment: Use `vpath` or write compilation rule (perhaps, an implicit one) for each source directory separately (i.e. `$(BUILD_DIR)%.o : $1%.cpp ;$(CXX) ...`).

Comment: Also move `mkdir` into the separate order-only prerequisite/rule.

Comment: Sure will do! Realised that command runs each time an object file is generated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by [Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4419802/matt) you have (at least) two options:

1. A compilation rule:

   ```
   # $(1): source file
   define MY_RULE
   $$(patsubst %.cpp,$$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o,$$(notdir $(1))): $(1)
       @mkdir -p "$$(BUILD_DIR)"
       $$(CXX) $$(CFLAGS) -I. -c $$< -o $$@
   endef
   $(foreach f,$(SOURCE_FILES),$(eval $(call MY_RULE,$(f))))
   ```

   Note the `$$` used to escape the first expansion (see [The eval Function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Eval-Function) for a detailed explanation).
2. The [`vpath` directive](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Selective-Search):

   ```
   vpath %.cpp $(dir $(SOURCE_FILES))

   $(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp
       @mkdir -p "$(BUILD_DIR)"
       $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -I. -c $< -o $@
   ```

Comment: This was really useful! However, I wonder if there are differences in build times with these two approaches. And also I'm going to read more about the vpath directive. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @Ganesh `I wonder if there are differences in build times with these two approaches` If there's only one `$(BUILD_DIR)` then there should be no difference. Otherwise, the first one could be better.